# How to groupby one column and then divide two columns together?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas, and I want to create a new column in my pandas dataframe. I'd like to groupby one column, and then divide two other columns together.

This perfectly works:

```
 df['new_col'] = (df.col2/df.col3)
```

However, when I groupby another column, what I have doesn't work:

```
 df['new_col'] = df.groupby('col1')(df.col2/df.col3)
```

Does anyone know how I can rewrite the above code? Thanks.

Comment: apply is the one you need to check

Answer (score 6):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Col1=list('AAAABBBB'),
    Col2=range(1, 9, 1),
    Col3=range(9, 1, -1)
))

df

df.groupby('Col1').sum().eval('Col4 = Col2 / Col3')

  Col1  Col2  Col3
0    A     1     9
1    A     2     8
2    A     3     7
3    A     4     6
4    B     5     5
5    B     6     4
6    B     7     3
7    B     8     2
```

---

**Solution**
Using `pd.DataFrame.eval`
We can use `eval` to create new columns in a pipeline

```
df.groupby('Col1', as_index=False).sum().eval('Col4 = Col2 / Col3')

  Col1  Col2  Col3      Col4
0    A    10    30  0.333333
1    B    26    14  1.857143
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 4, 3], ['B', 2, 4], ['C', 5, 1], ['A', 5, 1], ['B', 2, 7]],
                  columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])

#   Col1  Col2  Col3
# 0    A     4     3
# 1    B     2     4
# 2    C     5     1
# 3    A     5     1
# 4    B     2     7

df['Col4'] = df['Col2'] / df['Col3']
df = df.sort_values('Col1')

#   Col1  Col2  Col3      Col4
# 0    A     4     3  1.333333
# 3    A     5     1  5.000000
# 1    B     2     4  0.500000
# 4    B     2     7  0.285714
# 2    C     5     1  5.000000
```

Or if you need to perform a `groupby.sum` first:

```
df = df.groupby('Col1', as_index=False).sum()
df['Col4'] = df['Col2'] / df['Col3']

#   Col1  Col2  Col3      Col4
# 0    A     9     4  2.250000
# 1    B     4    11  0.363636
# 2    C     5     1  5.000000
```

Comment: Hey @jp_data_analysis, the first code ( df.groupby('Col1').apply(lambda row: row['Col2'] / row['Col3']) ) works, but not as a new column to the dataframe. Any idea how I can add it as a column?

Comment: But I'm not sure what exactly what you're looking for. Expected output would be great.